# Selecting character(0) from a list

Tags: r, list, vector

This is (part of) the dput() output of a List that I've got.

```
L<-list(c("LumenVox LLC", "LumenVox LLC", "Voxware Inc", "LumenVox LLC", 
        "Voxware Inc", "Voxant Inc"),character(0), character(0), character(0), 
        character(0), c("HumanZyme Inc", "ZymeQuest Inc", "Zymetx Inc", 
        "Zymetx Inc"))
[[1]]
[1] "LumenVox LLC" "LumenVox LLC" "Voxware Inc"  "LumenVox LLC" "Voxware Inc"  "Voxant Inc"  

[[2]]
character(0)

[[3]]
character(0)

[[4]]
character(0)

[[5]]
character(0)

[[6]]
[1] "HumanZyme Inc" "ZymeQuest Inc" "Zymetx Inc"    "Zymetx Inc"
```

It either contains a character vector, or character(0).. I want to select only the elements that are written as character(0) but I don't know how. Could anyone help me with this?

Comment: I don't think the dupe tagged is correct as the OP is asking for something else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `Filter`

```
Filter(Negate(length), L)
```

---

Or another option is `sapply`

```
L[!sapply(L, length)]
```

Or as @MartinMorgan mentioned `lengths` (introduced in the recent R version) can be used (which would be faster)

```
L[!lengths(L))
```

Comment: oh! so, character(0) has no length. Thanks!

Comment: better to use `L[lengths(L) == 0L)` which avoids iteration over loop elements at the R level.